# Remove extra parameters from framed JSON-LD

Tags: json, rdf, semantic-web, json-ld

So, lets consider the following data fetched from db:

```
[
  {
    "@id": "http://example.com/1",
    "http://example.com/label": "Parent",
    "http://example.com/status": "Active",
    "http://example.com/children": [
      {
        "@id": "http://example.com/2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@id": "http://example.com/2",
    "http://example.com/label": "Child",
    "http://example.com/status": "Active"
  }
]
```

And the frame:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://example.com/",
    "@vocab": "http://example.com/"
  },
  "@graph": {
    "status":{}
  }
}
```

The result will look like:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://example.com/",
    "@vocab": "http://example.com/"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "1",
      "children": {
        "@id": "2",
        "label": "Child",
        "status": "Active"
      },
      "label": "Parent",
      "status": "Active"
    },
    {
      "@id": "2",
      "label": "Child",
      "status": "Active"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see in the first object, in the `children` section I get some extra parameters in addition to id.

Is there a way I could simplify the `children` list to just contain ids:

```
"children": [
    "2"
]
```

I tried adding this to my frame:

```
"children": {
  "@id": "http://example.com/children",
  "@type": "@id"
}
```

But it doesn't work as I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [framing flags](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11-framing/#framing-flags): `"@embed": "@never"` or `"@explicit": true`.

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://example.com/",
    "@vocab": "http://example.com/"
  },
  "@graph": {
    "status": {},
    "@embed": "@never"
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://example.com/",
    "@vocab": "http://example.com/"
  },
  "@graph": {
    "status": {},
    "children": {"@explicit": true, "@omitDefault": true}
  }
}
```

But perhaps all you need is [compaction](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11-api/#compaction).

If you don't want to compact arrays, toggle the respective [option](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11-api/#dom-jsonldoptions-compactarrays). In JSONLD-Java:

```java
final JsonLdOptions options = new JsonLdOptions();
options.setCompactArrays(false);
```

---

Playground: [1](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F1%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel%22%3A%22Parent%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fstatus%22%3A%22Active%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fchildren%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F2%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F2%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel%22%3A%22Child%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fstatus%22%3A%22Active%22%7D%5D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%2C%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%7B%22status%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22%40embed%22%3A%22%40never%22%7D%7D), [2](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F1%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel%22%3A%22Parent%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fstatus%22%3A%22Active%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fchildren%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F2%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F2%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel%22%3A%22Child%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fstatus%22%3A%22Active%22%7D%5D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%2C%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%7B%22status%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22children%22%3A%7B%22%40explicit%22%3Atrue%2C%22%40omitDefault%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D), [3](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-compacted&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F1%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel%22%3A%22Parent%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fstatus%22%3A%22Active%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fchildren%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F2%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F2%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel%22%3A%22Child%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fstatus%22%3A%22Active%22%7D%5D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%2C%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%7B%22status%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22%40embed%22%3A%22%40never%22%7D%7D&context=%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%2C%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%7D).

Answer (score 0):

With this frame

```
    {
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://example.com/",
    "@vocab": "http://example.com/",
    "children": {"@type": "@id"}
  },
  "@graph": {
    "status":{},
    "children": {
        "@embed": "@never"
    }
  }
}
```

this is the result

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://example.com/",
    "@vocab": "http://example.com/",
    "children": {
      "@type": "@id"
    }
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "1",
      "children": "2",
      "label": "Parent",
      "status": "Active"
    },
    {
      "@id": "2",
      "children": null,
      "label": "Child",
      "status": "Active"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**